# How to add jQuery to the client side of a Hapi Js app without manually adding it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, hapi.js

I've used MeteorJS and ruby on rails for a while now, but when i decided to learn HapiJS i tried adding some jQuery to my view, the browser couldn't identify the symbol `$`. Later on when i included a jQuery CDN to my view using:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

and reloaded the server, jQuery was recognized.
I tried `npm install --save jquery` and assigning `var $ = require('jquery')` but obviously this failed since this code would run on the server not the client.
So is there a way to serve jquery without resorting to this include script? I am looking for a rails or meteorJS-like approach.

Comment: Compile your code using webpack to convert node server style code into client side.  Then you can manage deps easier.

Comment: So is this the only way? No built-in functions??

Comment: Sorry built in functions for what?

Comment: to add jQuery. you know like in rails, you get everything out of the box in a gem and in meteorJS it's just there

Comment: Then stick to those if that's what you prefer, meteorjs looks like a totally different architecture to client / server and so for that fact does ruby on rails.